# How do I disable auto upgrades for gke masters (not just node pools)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

A little confused about this. Reading google docs say auto upgrade is enabled for masters and node pools. But I can only find how to disable auto upgrade on node pools.

How do I disable auto upgrade on masters too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google documentation [states](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Cluster%20control%20planes%20are%20always%20upgraded%20on%20a%20regular%20basis%2C%20regardless%20of%20whether%20your%20cluster%20is%20enrolled%20in%20a%20release%20channel%20or%20not.):

> Note: Cluster control planes are always upgraded on a regular basis, regardless of whether your cluster is enrolled in a release channel or not.

So you can disable or enable auto-update for node pools but masters (control plane) has auto-updates always enabled.

Another quote from [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/release-channels?authuser=1#no_channel):

> Regardless of whether your cluster is enrolled in a release channel or not, cluster control planes are always upgraded on a regular basis.

Comment: Should add even if you disable node upgrades GKE will still FORCE upgrade your node pools if the version falls out of support. This happened to me a few times already. You should have an upgrade strategy in place and expect to do upgrades regularly if using GKE.

Answer (score 1):

The docs do a poor job of explaining this.

To disable auto-node upgrades you disable auto upgrades on the node pool. To disable auto master upgrades you set the release channel to not specified.

Using Terraform it's configured here:

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool#auto_upgrade
- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#release_channel

Comment: No, you can't disable mater auto-upgrade even if you set the release channel to not specified(static version). see this https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-schedule#schedule-for-static-no-channel
Note: The control planes of the clusters on static versions are upgraded automatically on or after the dates specified in the Auto Upgrade column of the Stable release channel schedule. When choosing a version older than the default version, you can use maintenance exclusions to prevent a cluster from being automatically upgraded until its end of life date.

Answer (score 0):

The GKE team performs [automatic upgrades](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/versioning-and-upgrades#automatic_cp_upgrades) of your cluster control plane on your behalf and this is managed by Google in order to ensure security patches and functionality. As per [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-container-cluster#upgrade_cp) you can manually initiate a control plane upgrade to a version newer than the default.

Also, you can disable node auto-upgrade for an [existing node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-upgrades#disable). Keep in mind if you do so, you have to make sure that the cluster's nodes run a version compatible the cluster's version.

```
gcloud container node-pools update node-pool-name --cluster cluster-name \
--zone compute-zone --no-enable-autoupgrade
```

Also, this [article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades) explains further how automatic and manual upgrades work on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters.

Comment: this is not true auto upgrades can be disabled for the masters

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stop GKE Control Plane auto upgrade, but you can stop control plan auto-upgrade for some period by using gke maintenance exclusion window

Doc : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/maintenance-windows-and-exclusions

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't disable mater auto-upgrade even if you set the release channel to not specified(static version). see this https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-schedule#schedule-for-static-no-channel
Note: The control planes of the clusters on static versions are upgraded automatically on or after the dates specified in the Auto Upgrade column of the Stable release channel schedule. When choosing a version older than the default version, you can use maintenance exclusions to prevent a cluster from being automatically upgraded until its end of life date.